# find all variants, of attributes [JS]

Tags: javascript, node.js, math

this is a bit tricky task, can't find any decent solution so far.

Lets say we have an array of attributes:

```
const input = [
  ['attr1_a', 'attr1_b'],
  ['attr2_a', 'attr2_b'],
  ['attr3_a', 'attr3_b', 'attr3_c'],
];
```

so I'm looking for some function `getAllVariants(input);` that will take as an attribute this array and output the following result:

```
const result = [
  ['attr1_a', 'attr2_a', 'attr3_a'],
  ['attr1_a', 'attr2_a', 'attr3_b'],
  ['attr1_a', 'attr2_a', 'attr3_c'],
  ['attr1_a', 'attr2_b', 'attr3_a'],
  ['attr1_a', 'attr2_b', 'attr3_b'],
  ['attr1_a', 'attr2_b', 'attr3_c'],
  ['attr1_b', 'attr2_a', 'attr3_a'],
  ['attr1_b', 'attr2_a', 'attr3_b'],
  ['attr1_b', 'attr2_a', 'attr3_c'],
  ['attr1_b', 'attr2_b', 'attr3_a'],
  ['attr1_b', 'attr2_b', 'attr3_b'],
  ['attr1_b', 'attr2_b', 'attr3_c'],
];
```

thanks for any help!

Comment: Where did `attr1_c` come from?

Comment: It sounds like the function `getAllVariants` doesn't exist, and maybe that's why you don't have a solution for now. Try creating the function and give it a body with some loops in it

Comment: sorry typo, no `attr1_c`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
        const input = [{
                attributes: ['attr1_a', 'attr1_b']
            },
            {
                attributes: ['attr2_a', 'attr2_b']
            },
            {
                attributes: ['attr3_a', 'attr3_b', 'attr3_c']
            }
        ];
        
        var parts = input.map(val => val.attributes),
            result = parts.reduce((a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => [].concat(v, w))), []));
        
        console.log(result);
```

Comment: Instead of just adding code, can you add an explanation of what's happening - this is too easy to promote copy and paste which is not what SO is about

Comment: @DarrenSweeney It was not my intention, If you feel like that I'll remove my post.

Comment: All I'm saying is it's helpful to explain why your code works in relation to the question - great that you've answered, and it's been accepted. I just think of other less experienced developers who might have the same question, might not understand why your code works

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I understood what you are trying to say, It works as expected if I remove join, I forgot to remove **join(',')**